# Can LINQ GroupBy clause contain an operation?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm having an odd situation with some LINQ that is not generating the response I expect.

The following groups in the way I'd expect (two groups: one for odd numbers, one for even numbers):

```
var ints = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var foo = from i in ints
    group i by i % 2 into g
    select new {
        Key = g.Key,
        Group = g
    };
```

When I do the following similar query on a MySQL database (using IQ Driver), it results in something completely unintuitive: a separate "group" for each entry in the database.

```
var bar = from f in MYDATABASE_TABLE.Take(10)
    group f by f.Uid % 2 into g // where Uid is an int
    select new {
        Key = g.Key,
        Group = g
    };
```

Does any one have any ideas on why this is behaving so oddly? The GroupBy clause seems to be behaving weird if I add any sort of operation to it. (For example, you can try a random number generator for 0s and 1s (e.g. replace the "f.Uid % 2" clause with random.Next(1)), and it does something similar.)

Edit: Took out references to "linq-to-sql", which turn out to be incorrect, and added explicit reference to IQ Driver.

Comment: Linq-to-SQL... on MySQL?

Comment: Yes, on MySQL (sorry -- didn't know this would make a difference).

Comment: @Tony, the question was asked because LinqToSql does not support MySQL.

Comment: @John and @Kirk: Okay, thanks. I must be in over my head. I'm using LINQ to query the MySQL database using the MySQL Connector. Does this mean that the MySQL Connector is only supporting a subset of LINQ? And/or I'm using the term "LinqToSql" incorrectly?

Comment: I "misspoke" about using MySQL Connector (sorry). I'm actually using the IQ Driver through LINQPad.

Comment: Note that you are grouping into three groups: even numbers, positive odd numbers and negative odd numbers. The possible outputs of x%2 are -1, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested, but I've done something similar):

```
var bar = from f in MYDATABASE_TABLE.Take(10)
    let u = f.Uid % 2
    group f by u into g // where Uid is an int
    select new {
        Key = g.Key,
        Group = g
    };
```

I could be wrong about this, but it should be easy to try.

Comment: Good idea. I tried this just now through LINQPad, and unfortunately, it still generated the odd response. My guess is that it's treating the clause between "by" and "into" as an "let's evaluate this later" or something, but I don't have a good sense for how the internals work.

Comment: @Tony - Yeah, the `let` clause should just be syntactic sugar, so I figured it was a long shot. I know I've done this before. I'll see if I can find my old code.

Comment: Based on responses from other folks, do you remember/know what database your code was running against?

Comment: @Tony - It was MS-SQL. And it may have been L2Entities as well. So you could be out of luck.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks, dude! My interpretation is that L2SQL, L2Entities and what I'm working with (IQ Driver) are all different beasts. This was a big surprise for me, but good to find out.